# Change all ImageViews in ListView to a particular image

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I'm trying to make an audio file preview page which consists of a `listview` of files in a folder. Each `row` has a `play button` next to it which changes to a `stop button` when clicked. I now need a way of setting all the other `images` to the `play button` if a row is clicked as only one `audio file` should be playing at once. I tried iterating through the list and getting the `imageview` from this but had no luck (shown below):

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);  

    IncidentLogger logger = new IncidentLogger(this.getActivity());
    final List<Audio> audioList = logger.getAllAudio();

    AudioListViewAdapter adapter = new AudioListViewAdapter(audioList, getActivity());

    final ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            for(int i = 0; i < audioList.size(); i++) {
                View v = listView.getAdapter().getView(i, view, parent);
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.control);
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_play);
            }

            ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.control);

            if(iv.getTag() == "1") {
                iv.setTag("0");
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_play);
            } else {
                iv.setTag("1");
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_stop);
            }               
        }
    };

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done so easily, you need to just look at on the position of list item that was clicked by user. A well described complete demo code is as below ...

```
 public class ChangeImageInListDynamically extends Activity {
/**
 * Adapter for your data. 
 */
ImageAdapter adpAR;
ArrayList<String> itemList;
ListView mListView;
ImageAdapter mAdapter;

/**
 * Indicate which item is currently selected.  
 * Its default selected item is '0' e.g., 1st item. 
 */
private int selectedPosition=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    itemList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        itemList.add("Item - "+i);
    }

    mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.data_list);

    //Initialize your adapter
    mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(nChangeImageInListDynamically.this, itemList);

    //set adapter to your list.
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    //set list click listener.
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View view, int position, long id) {
            //your image that need to change dynamically.
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.select);

            //position of clicked item.  
            selectedPosition=position;

            //change image of respective image.
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.selected);

            //notify your adapter to update your list.  
            adpAR.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView title;
    ImageView img;                  
}   

/**
 * Your ImageAdapter.
 */
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<String> dataList;
    Context context;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.dataList = arrayList;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return dataList.size();;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;

        final ViewHolder holder;
        Log.d("posiiton ImageAdapater : ",""+position);
        if (row == null) { 
            LayoutInflater inflater = ChangeImageInListDynamically.this.getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.img = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.select);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        //set titel text.
        holder.title.setText(dataList.get(position));

        //Change Image of selected item dynamically.
             if(selectedPosition == position) {
                 //Item is selected.
                 holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.selected);

             }else{
                 //Other non-selected items.
                 holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.dis_selected);

             }

        return row;

    }

 }

}
```